# Defining 'this' after a click

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I have a bunch of ajax functions I'm firing up on events (click, dblclick, keypress etc.)
At the start of my events.js file I'd like to define a variable which represents the id of the element the user clicks on. It's currently

```
$(this).parents('li').attr('data-id')
```

So far I tried this way :

```
var element_id = $(this).parents('li').attr('data-id');

var test = function(id)
{
    ajaxCall(id);
}

$('.js_btn_test').live('click', function()
{
    test(element_id);
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. I thought the element_id var would be parsed when I click on .js_btn_test and be evaluated as its parent 'li', then fetch the data-id.

Thanks for your help !

EDIT1 : Basic HTML structure

It looks like this

```
<li data-id="<?php echo $item->getId(); ?>">
    <button class="js_btn_test">Test</button>
</li>
```

Comment: Please add (some) HTML source code to your post

Comment: why not just give it an id.. and then do: .attr("id")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it doesn't work like that. With...

`var element_id = $(this).parents('li').attr('data-id');`

... you assign a value to `element_id` variable *immediately*, and not depending on what will be `this` when you check its value next time.

One possible workaround is to use a function instead:

```
var getElementId = function(el) {
  return $(el).parents('li').attr('data-id');
};
...
$('.js_btn_test').live('click', function() {
   test(getElementId(this));
});
```

... as `this` within an event handler (the anonymous function you pass to `live`) refers to the element which fired an event.

As a sidenote, you can swap `.attr('data-id')` for just `.data('id')` call, as shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MgWEj/) and described [here](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5).

Comment: So there's no way to do it for multiple events/elements in the 'li' ? For example if I want to get the data-id when double clicking on another button with the class .js_btn_test2

Comment: Why, you can reuse that function in `dblclick` event handler. The key point is that function will be executed each time you call it, but an assignment is a single-time event.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do is put the logic that fetches an `id` based on the clicked element into a variable. That's not possible unless you make it a function (in which case there's no need to make it a variable at all).

For example:

```
function getIdFromElement(el) {
    return $(el).parents('li').attr('data-id');
}

$('.js_btn_test').live('click', function()
{
    test(getIdFromElement(this));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot resolve `this` properly before it is executed in its proper context.

```
var test = function(id)
{
    ajaxCall(id);
}

$('.js_btn_test').live('click', function()
{
    var element_id = $(this).parents('li').attr('data-id');
    test(element_id);

    func01(element_id);
    func02(element_id);
    // etc
}
```

Comment: I know, that's exactly what I'm trying to achieve. I have 30+ functions so I'd like to use a variable instead of copying $(this).parents('li').attr('data-id') each time in case I want to refactor.

Comment: @Ping - then call those 30+ functions from `click` handler.

Comment: >You cannot resolve this properly before it is executed in its proper context.

Ok, thanks a lot for your answer !

Comment: @Ping - you have not mentioned when and how those 30+ functions are executed. Are they procedures? Event handlers? You are asking recommendations for architecture here and without proper background, it is pretty much shooting in the dark.

Comment: They're all event handlers. I organised my javascript structure as follows : events.js catches all events (clicks, dbl clicks, keypress, keyup, mouseover...) and calls ajax functions defined in ajax_functions.js. Then the ajax_functions go through an ajax_router.php file that calls the right objects. I'm not quite sure this is a good practice but it worked quite well in my small projects.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get `this` because its not in context yet.

Also `live` is deprecated in the latest version of jquery.

Here is an extract from the jquery website

***As of jQuery 1.7**, the `.live()` method is deprecated. Use `.on()` to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use `.delegate()` in preference to `.live()`.*

```
var test = function(id)
{
    ajaxCall(id);
}

$('.js_btn_test').on('click', function()
{
    var element_id = $(this).parents('li').attr('data-id');
    test(element_id);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll use the on() method. I guess I'm stuck with declaring element_id in each function !